# Extrapolating/predicting non-linear using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat

I want to be able use the stat_smooth function in ggplot to extrapolate/predict using a regression model, via a non-linear function. Is there a way to do this? I have been trying this on the Iris dataset, but seem to be getting strange results? See below my code and the attached image. I understand that there will be some uncertainty as I am trying to predict well outside the known range

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x + I(x^2), size = 1,
              fullrange = T)+xlim(0,100)
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the strange result? What were you expecting? If you want modeling advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se]. ggplot should really just be used for visualization. If you want to actually work with and interpret a model, you should fit it outside of ggplot where you have more control.

Comment: This is the result you would expect based on the model you have provided. You are fitting a squared term, and the coefficient for the squared term that best fits the data is negative, so the curve is an inverted parabola. If you extrapolate far enough outside the range of the original data, this curve is going to cross into predicting negative values. That's clearly nonsense, but nonsense is what you are likely to get if you try to extrapolate most models as far as you are extrapolating this one.